# How to get base BSSID of the Access point

Tags: android

We have access points configured with multiple SSIDs(Networks) in our office.
In this setup, the BSSID of the ScanResult gives the BSSID of the individual SSID only.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html.

That getBSSID() returns only the BSSID of the individual SSIDs. In the multiple SSID configured scenario, we are getting a array of list in the ScanResult . Each list gives different BSSID, which concludes it is the BSSID of SSIDs & not the Accesspoints. This BSSID is same as the one we are getting from the WifiInfo.

But we have a requirement to get the MAC address or the base BSSID of the Access point.  Please let me know, how to get the Access point's BSSID.

To be precise, we want to group the SSIDs based on Acces points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I find the MAC address of my Access point in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063889/can-i-find-the-mac-address-of-my-access-point-in-android)

Comment: No it is not. That getBSSID() returns only the BSSID of the individual SSIDs. In the multiple SSID configured scenario, we are getting a array of list in the ScanResult . Each list gives different BSSID, which concludes it is the BSSID of SSIDs & not the Accesspoints. This BSSID is same we are getting in the WifiInfo.

Comment: Did you solve it somehow? I have the same issue.