# Is it possible to get the router brand throught the Wifi?

Tags: android, wifi

Is it possible to get the router brand from the Wifi spot that the user is currently using?

I would like to know if the router brand is technicolor, thomson and...

Thank you.

Comment: you want name of router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the Mac address of the router the user Is connected to, you can then use [Wireshark's OUI database](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf) in order to guess the brand of the router.

You can check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063889/can-i-find-the-mac-address-of-my-access-point-in-android) to see how to get the current APs MAC in android.

Furthermore, the site [WikiDevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Main_Page) has the most comprehensive wireless device DB I know of. You can get the relationship router-interface brand from the respective product page.

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

In Code

```
public String getWifiName(Context context) {
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
   if (wifiInfo != null) {
      DetailedState state = WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState());
      if (state == DetailedState.CONNECTED || state == DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {
          return wifiInfo.getSSID();
      }
   }
}
return null;
 }
```

Comment: With that code I can get the wifi name, you are right, but i want to get the router brand, like I said in my question... But thanks btw