# Does Android WifiManager saves the Config even without saveConfiguration()

Tags: android, wifimanager

I am developing and app for a restaurant. They want their customers to connect their Wifi via app.

The code:

```
WifiManager mManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
//Asume I added things to config.
int id = mManager.addNetwork(config);
mManager.enableNetwork(id, true);
```

So even if I don't call

```
myManager.saveConfiguration();
```

can the device connect that Router without my app?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I read about it [more](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring11/group02/documents/matt_appnote.pdf) and [more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html), I found the answer. And also the solution.

So, you need to use use

```
mManager.removeNetwork(id);
```

after it is disconnected. I assume you saved your BSSID's in somewhere. Also save the ID that you got. With a Timer task working at background check the current BSSID, if it is not the same, remove the ID from Configured Networks as above.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063889/can-i-find-the-mac-address-of-my-access-point-in-android) is how you check current BSSID:

```
 WifiInfo wifiInfo = mManager.getConnectionInfo();
 String currentBSSID = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
```