# How to get Wireless Router mac address?

Tags: java, android

How to get Wireless Router Information like Router MAC address from Android using Java?
Like the screenshot below(Taken from WiFiman app from Android )

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4fJ0.jpg)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063889/can-i-find-the-mac-address-of-my-access-point-in-android)

Comment: In above android 6.0 it always returns 02:00:00:00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the MAC address (BSSID) for the wifi network you are connected to then you can do the following:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
info.getBSSID();
```

If you want to loop throught the available wifi networks you can do this:

WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().
                getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

```
    List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < mScanResults.size(); i++)
        try {
            mScanResults.get(i).SSID; // the access point name (SSID)
            mScanResults.get(i).BSSID; // the access point MAC (BSSID)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //....
        }
```

Don't forget the required permission in you manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

EDIT: the above code works for Android below 6.. To achive it for newer devices pleace check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159224/getting-mac-address-in-android-6-0)

Comment: Tried this solution but above 6.0 it returns 02:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: I took that from an old project my bad.. I added an edit however to with a link for the newer approach

Comment: Tried all the solutions in your edited link. but none of them works. I'm using 9.0.1